# Using webpack to prepend variables for SCSS

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, react-toolbox

Webpack amateur here... I'm trying to incorporate a `theme.scss` file to customize the theme used by React Toolbox by following the directions specified [here](http://react-toolbox.com/#/install), namely:

> If you are using Webpack as module bundler, you are probably using sass-loader as well. What we want to do is to prepend to each SASS file compilation a bunch of variables to override and this can be done with the data option. For example:
>
> sassLoader: { data: '@import "' + path.resolve(__dirname, 'theme/_theme.scss') + '";' }
>
> In this case we have are prepending the theme import to each SASS compilation so the primary color will be changed in every single stylesheet.

I'm having trouble implementing this instruction with my current webpack configuration, which looks like this:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
let ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
    entry: [
        './main.js',
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'www'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    'babel-loader',
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                            sourceMap: true,
                            importLoaders: 1,
                            localIdentName: "[name]--[local]--[hash:base64:8]"
                        }
                    },
                    "postcss-loader" // has separate config, see postcss.config.js nearby
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader', options: {
                                sourceMap: true,
                                data: '@import "' + path.resolve(__dirname, 'theme.scss') + '";'
                            }
                        },
                        'postcss-loader',
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader', options: {
                                sourceMap: true,
                                data: '@import "' + path.resolve(__dirname, 'theme.scss') + '";'
                            }
                        },
                    ],
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: 'style.css',
            allChunks: true
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
        ],
    },
};
```

I don't get an error, but it seems like the `data` option is being entirely ignored because my file does not get imported.

Here is my `theme.scss` file (located in `client/theme.scss`):

```
@import "~react-toolbox/lib/colors";

$color-primary: $palette-red-500;
$color-primary-dark: $palette-red-700;

body {
  background-color: black; //testing
}
```

I feel like I must be doing something stupid here, but I'm driving myself crazy. I have tried messing with the path of the `theme.scss` file (changing the `data` attribute to `data: '@import "' + path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/theme.scss') + '";'`) but that doesn't make a difference. I'm surprised I'm not getting an error of some kind.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you found a solution ? I am having the same issue and the given answer does not solve it.

Answer (score 6):

The below configuration worked for me

```
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    include: /client/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style-loader',
      loader: [
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          query: {
            modules: true,
            sourceMap: false,
            localIdentName: '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]',
          },
        },
        'postcss-loader',
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          query: {
            sourceMap: false,
            data: `@import "${path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/_theme.scss')}";`
          }
        }
      ],
    }),
  },
```

and `client/_theme.scss` file

```
@import "react-toolbox/lib/colors.css";

$color-primary: var(--palette-blue-500);
$color-primary-dark: var(--palette-blue-700);
```

I checked the `colors.css` file in the `react-toolbox` library and used the same variable names. i.e `--palette-blue-500`, not `$palette-blue-500`.

Comment: OP is likely long gone, but just wanted to say this answered a similar question I had. +1